# Permission Denied in assetic with less

Tags: assetic

I'm getting odd permission issues when trying to use assetic with LESS. When I try to view the output page, I get:

```
/*
[exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | Assetic\Exception\FilterException
[message] An error occurred while running:
&#039;&#039; &#039;/tmp/assetic_lessdbtWog&#039;

Error Output:
sh: 1: : Permission denied


Input:
@import &quot;../../../bundles/orkestraapplication/css/src/less/application.less&quot;;

@images-path: &quot;../../../bundles/orkestraapplication/img&quot;;

.table-striped &gt; tbody &gt; tr.admin-appointment &gt; td  {
  background-color: #FFEBBD;
}
```

The thing is, I'm unable to figure out what file's permissions it thinks are wrong. I've even tried a

```
chmod 777 * -R
```

on the entire app folder, and that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this issue is related to how Assetic uses node. Assetic does less compilation using node. It will concatenate the path to node with the path to a temp file that has the less to be compiled. If you don't have a node path set up, it will wind up just executing the temp file, which is unlikely to have execution permissions, thus the error.